# Ruby on rails associations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two files.

**clans.rb**

```
class Clans < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :User
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :Clan
end
```

I also have two mysql tables.

**clans:** id | name | prefix | description | user_id

**users:** id | username | password | email | bindcode

clans.user_id being users.id of the clan leader.

In my code I can use the following in show.html.erb and it gives me the clan name.

```
<%= Clans.find(params[:id]).name %>
```

But I want to be able to do: Clans.find(params[:id]).leader.(users fields)
Example:

```
<%= Clans.find(params[:id]).leader.username %>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to name your user property as 'leader'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Clan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leader, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :clan
end
```

Notice the class change from `Clans` to `Clan` and
association change from `has_one :Clan` to `has_one :clan`

Comment: Thanks, this achieves what I wanted =D

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can achieve this:

```
belongs_to :leader, :class_name=>"User", :foreign_key=>"user_id"
```

Or

```
belongs_to :user
delegate :leader, :to=>:user
```

Note: The latter version will still allow you to do `clan.user`, as well as `clan.leader`.

Answer (score 0):

`belongs_to :user` not `belongs_to :User`

same issue with `Clans`

Comment: This fixed it, mind explaining why? I dont really understand it.